# How to intercept Akka messages in persistence view in tests?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

With actors I can write something like that:

```
val echo = system.actorOf("someActorName")
echo ! "hello world"
expectMsg("hello world")
```

But how I can intercept messages which are replicated to persistence view?

Comment: What do you mean by ` replicated to persistence view`?

Comment: You can intercept messages by putting an extra actor in between.

Comment: About "replicated" messages from Persistence Actor also send to persistence view of that actor.